# Disable davfs2 caching

Tags: ubuntu, davfs2

There is a problem with undesirable caching of a file by davfs2. A large backup .tar.gz file (4052 Mb) is created on another partition and uploaded. During the process, its copy is created at `/var/cache/davfs2/` and results in unnecessary occupation of disk space on main partion.

Cache-related options were disabled `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` and were accepted by davfs2 but had no positive effect:

```
cache_size 0
delay_upload 0
```

Here's a relevant piece of syslog:

```
Mar 27 03:00:01 ubuntu mount.davfs: davfs2 1.4.7
Mar 27 03:00:01 ubuntu mount.davfs: /sbin/mount.davfs <...> -o rw
<...>
Mar 27 03:12:16 ubuntu mount.davfs: open files exceed max cache size by 4052 MiBytes
```

How can caching behaviour be totally disabled, so no space would be wasted for davfs2 cache?

Comment: I dont think davfs2 can work without the cache. You might try a simpler program like `cadaver`, that tries to propose a ftp-like command set.

Comment: @meuh Thanks, I will keep it in mind. I'm about to update the script to stream .tar.gz to the server, so I guess that mountable WebDAV is my best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found mounted DAVFS2 shares to be unusable with my storage provider, in combination with many/large files. So I used simple curl wrapper commands for streaming files to a remote server. No tmp files needed!

```
echo "Creating folder: $(curl -sK /etc/davfs2/curl -X MKCOL $backup_url/$tag)"
echo "Uploading zipped files: $($tarcmd | curl -T- -sK /etc/davfs2/curl $backup_url/$tag/$today.tar.xz)"
echo "Uploading zipped SQL dump: $(mysqldump db_$tag | xz | curl -T- -sK /etc/davfs2/curl $backup_url/$tag/$today.sql.xz)"
```

My `/etc/davfs2/curl` contains `--user <USER>:<PASS>`

Comment: Nowadays (2021), for a more programmatic sync alternative,  `rclone` might come handy: https://rclone.org/webdav/